# $.weekline is not a function in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, weekday

In spite of including all the references for the Weekline plugin the browser shows the error that `weekline is not a function`. I am trying this in an ASP.Net MVC View

```html
<script src="~/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/jquery.weekLine.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.weekLine.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/jquery.weekLine-white.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td height="50" width="100">
      <div class="weekDays" title="weekdays" id="weekdays"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="25" width="100">
      <div id="selectedDays"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$("#weekdays").weekLine();
$("#weekdays").weekLine({
  onChange: function() {
    $("#selectedDays").html($(this).weekLine('getSelected', 'indexes'));
  }
});
```

Comment: You're loading weekline before jQuery.js. There should be a separate error in the console about that. You need to organise your scripts so jQuery comes first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @RoryMcCrossan . It worked for me.